# How can I download content of div using html2canvas and FileSaver in the dowllaods folder instead of in the browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html2canvas

I'm struggling to figure this out:
When user clicks on button it creates a png of whatever the content is in my "imagecontainer" element. 
Unfortunately it only adds a canvas with the png to the bottom of my page. How can I prevent it from doing that and let the png get straight into dowloads folder or new window?? Thank you so much.
This is my code:

```js
$(function() { 
    $("#savebutton").click(function() { 
        html2canvas($(".imagecontainer"), {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
                theCanvas = canvas;
                document.body.appendChild(canvas);

                canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
     save(blob, "Dashboard.png"); 
    });

            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: You can of course not make _anything_ “go straight to the download folder”, that would be a huge security issue. The most you can do is trigger a download dialog, so that user can decide whether to save the offered resource and where.

Comment: okay that makes sense, can you open it in a new tab though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you append an element to `document.body` it's naturally placed in the bottom of the page. Append your canvas to the element you want to contain it. For example to `imagecontainer`:

```
$(".imagecontainer").append(canvas);
```